# how to display the go back style UIBarButtonItem programmatically

Tags: iphone

When One of my app navigate from one controller to another, the 'go back'              UIBarButtonItem disappear, so I wrote codes:

```
        UIBarButtonItem *barButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                      target:self
                                                                      action:@selector(barButtonItemPressed:)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton1;
        [barButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fdj.png"]];
        [barButton1 release];
```

It works, but it display as

[image]

but I prefer the style (like standard go back barbuttonitem

[image]

Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Comment: you might have to use exact image (with arrowed left side) for that I think..

Comment: use custom bar button with exact image

Answer (score 2):

You should edit the `navigationItem` of the parent view controller:

You can place this in the `viewDidLoad` of the previous view controller:

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fdj.png"];
```

Comment: maybe there are something wrong in my codes, this does not work for me neither :-(

Comment: Just tested the code and it should work now. At least with the edit from 14min. ago. Make sure that you place the code in **PARENT** viewcontroller. The parent being the viewcontroller which pushes the viewcontroller you want to changed the backbutton for.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code how you can do this

```
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 36);
[btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBack"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBack"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *item4 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item4;
```

just make image and set it in uibutton, it's simple way to do this.
you can set any image you want.
hope this may help you what you want.

Comment: Wrong answer. There's a defined way to do this - and this isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

In the **parent** view controller's init method, set

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage: [UIimage imageNamed: @"fdj.png"] 
                                                                          style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                         target: nil 
                                                                         action: nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: If there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know so I can correct it.

Comment: 2 downvotes! Come on guys, fill me in... what's wrong with the answer?